# What is the best theoretical Big O for some ideal algorithm?

Tags: asymptotics

Big O notation has many commonly found real-world examples, like O(N), O(log N), O(N log N),... and so on.
Other than a constant Big-O like O(1), is there some theoretical golden "value" of O that some perfectly efficient algorithm could achieve, one that is faster than O(log N)? As in, an function with O([this expression]) could never be reduced to a less time-complex form?

Apologies if this is the wrong StackExchange for this, but this seems more a math question to me.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any sorting algorithm cant be faster than $O(nlogn)$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Probably CS is a better place for this type of questions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Personally I haven't heard of anything in between $O(1)$ and $O(logN)$ if that's the question.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, but it is very simple to construct an algorithm which has any complexity you like... If you want the complexity $f(n)$, then the algorithm "enumerate all numbers between 1 and $f(n)$" has exactly complexity $f(n)$... There are surely less stupid things one might do...

Comment: One challenge in finding a $o(\log N)$ algorithm is that it seems merely telling the function which value of $N$ it has to run on takes $O(\log N)$ time just passing in $N$'s digits. However, that's probably considered "free". For example, `def f(N): return 1` would usually be described as running in $O(1)$ time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between $O(\log n)$ and $O(1)$ are things like
$$
O(\log\log n)
\\
O(\sqrt{\log n})
$$
and lots of others.

Comment: I  think the question was whether one can construct (useful?) algorithms with such complexities in between.

Answer (score 1):

A famous example is given by the Union-Find problem, where the amortized time can be made $\Theta(\alpha(n))$ where $\alpha(n)$ is the Inverse Ackermann function, which is extremely slowly growing (slower than the iterated logarithm $\log^*(n)$). For all practical $n$, the function value does not exceed $5$ (it would take much much much more than the number of subsets of atoms in the universe to reach $5$).